# How to change right click from double to single

Tags: mouse, 17.04

Left click works just fine: one click for links and two for opening folders.
Right click is different than Windows: it uses one click for bringing the menu on the desktop and folders but I need to click twice to bring the menu on browsers, when clicking a link (I like to click and "open in new tab")

Is there a way to only change this specific behavior on right click?

Comment: I've never experienced this, at least not on 14.04. Which browsers are you using?

Comment: @wjandrea Chrome, now that you mentioned it works fine on Firefox

Comment: I use Chrome daily and I haven't experienced this.

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem on Edge 99.0.1150.11 @ Ubuntu 20.04